# UV map for hemisphere and other primitives

Tags: mesh, uv

completly newb here.
I need to construct some primitives for my ParticleSystems in Unity3D, but i have issues with UV maps. There is some mesh like a hemisphere

[image]

I need to put textures on this sphere, like this one

[image]

I just select all entire mesh by (A)>Unwarp, so its create default UV map, but this one is not much correct, like some distortion on top and not clear on bot.

[image]

Trying to google how to apply UV maps, but there is a lot of tutorials for hard-constructed mesh/texture but not a for simple one.

What i need is simple primitives and use non-unique textures for them correctly, would be nice if you have some tutros or w/e for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird that you have this result because with a simple UV Unwrap> Unwrap, it's automatically good, I just redesigned your texture so that I have a higher resolution but that's all. Maybe you have forgotten to give your object a *Subdivision* modifier, it will make your sphere smoother.

[image]

here is what it gives without the *Subdivision* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thx for respond. Yes, "Subdivision modifier" was added before i create UV map.

I guess reason of this "corrupted" UV map was my mesh wich is not exactly hemisphere, here is image 

https://imgur.com/4WISCSt

When i create a real hemisphere this texture works correct (Unfortunately i was need exactly my mesh, not hemisphere). 

https://imgur.com/JohmD8Q

Comment: my object is not an hemisphere as well so it's not the problem, it must be something else, are you sure you're making a simple unwrap (and no seams)?

Comment: also, have you enabled the eye and camera icons of the Subsurf modifier?

Comment: I'm an some special sort of idiot. When i create "Subsurf" i didnt click APPLY at all. Now my mesh with correct UV map, thx. (idk but when i export FBX for unity that was smooth mesh like with "Subsurf", so i didnt pay attention i guess, absolutly my fault).